Error: Unknown https cluster: mainnet
Hello im trying to make a bot that gets token metadata for the latest minted tokens on the solana blockchain. However whenever I run it I keep getting this error
Error: Unknown https cluster: mainnet
I tried to put the address there instead of just mainnet but that did not work either. This is my code below
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, Token } = require("@solana/spl-token");

async function main() {
    try {
        //  connection to the mainnet cluste
        const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet'), 'confirmed');

        // Fetches the blockhash (so we get the latest data as we are using the latest blockhash)
        const { blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

        // Fetch recent transactions on the block
        const block = await connection.getBlock(blockhash);

        // Get da token account addresses from transactions
        const tokenAccountAddresses = block.transactions.flatMap(tx => {
            return tx.transaction.message.accountKeys
                .filter(acc => acc.equals(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID))
                .map(acc => tx.transaction.message.accountKeys[acc.equals(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID) ? 1 : 0].toBase58());
        });

        // Gets unique token mint addresses
        const mintAddresses = [...new Set(tokenAccountAddresses)];

        // Fetches token metadata for each mint
        for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(mintAddresses.length, 5); i++) {
            const token = new Token(connection, mintAddresses[i], TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, null);

            // Fetch all token metadata
            const tokenInfo = await token.getMintInfo();
            console.log(`Token Metadata for ${mintAddresses[i]}:`);
            console.log(tokenInfo);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching the tokens metadata:", error);
    }
}

main();

This is the complete error:
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
Error fetching the tokens metadata: Error: Unknown https cluster: mainnet
at clusterApiUrl (C:\Users\rayof\node_modules@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:10992:11)
at main (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Solana sniper\solana.js:7:43)
at Object. (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Solana sniper\solana.js:39:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
I would appreciate if anyone could help me on fixing this, im completely new to all of this
Thanks!

The actual moniker for Solana mainnet is "mainnet-beta", so inputting that should work.
Additionally, "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/" should work as well.

Thank you so much! it worked now im not getting that error. I do have a different one now but ill try looking that up before asking here
